# ASP.NET Core Minimal Api Custom Middleware with authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET Core Minimal API Backend which uses JWT Authentication and authorization and Entity Framework code first database access
The User has Username and Password and each user is associated with an Institute, so the user class looks like this

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual Institute Institute { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

I have setup the JWT Authentication and Authorization based on this article: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/authorization-authentication-minimal-apis

What I want to achieve is I want a middleware which gets the user from the Authorization data and get the ID of associated institute and pass it to the api endpoints to get or create other resources based on the associated Institute

currently its implemented like this based on ChatGPT's answers in Program.cs:

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors(corsPolicyName);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    // Get the ClaimsPrincipal from the current request.
    Console.WriteLine("Middleware call");
    if (context.User is ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
    {
        foreach (var claim in claimsPrincipal.Claims)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{claim.Type}: {claim.Value}");
        }
        // Get the username from the ClaimsPrincipal.
        var username = claimsPrincipal.Identity?.Name;
        Console.WriteLine($"ClaimsPrinciple username: {username}");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            using var dbContext = new DatabaseContext();

            // Find the user in the database.
            var user = dbContext.Users
                .Include(u => u.Institute)
                .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);

            if (user != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Username: {username}, InstituteID: {user.Institute?.ID}");
                // Pass the InstituteID associated with the user to the API endpoint.
                context.Items["instituteID"] = user.Institute?.ID;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"User not found for username: {username}");
            }
        }
    }

    return next(context);
});

app.UseRouting();

// endpoints here
```

Doing this results in this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Endpoint HTTP: GET /timeslot/ => Get contains authorization metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports authorization.
Configure your application startup by adding app.UseAuthorization() in the application startup code. If there are calls to app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...), the call to app.UseAuthorization() must go between them.'
```

And If I re-order things based on the error message i.e. put `app.UseAuthorization()` after `app.UseRouting()` I get the username from the `ClaimsPrincipal` in the middleware as either Empty or Null (its not logged in console)

So how can get the authorization data in the middleware and make it work as intended or is there some other way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: `I want a middleware which gets the user from the Authorization data ... and pass it to the api endpoints to get or create` --> I'm sorry but I still wants to know why you want to have such a middleware, in my humble opinion, this should be handled inside the api endpoint. In my idea, the request contains data inside the request body, and inside the request header, we have a jwt token, in our api project, it validated the token and then routing the request to the api action method, then we handle the data.

Comment: @TinyWang I thought of using a middleware to not repeat code since it applies to most endpoints, what do you suggest I do? perhaps something like a function call in each endpoint which simply takes the ClaimsPrincipal and returns the Id?

Comment: yes...I also think so, we could create a function which used to do the operation you want to do in the middleware, and call this function in the endpoints where you want to do it.